# Metric space: bounded and completely bounded

Tags: general-topology

I can find a huge ball that will contain my whole space -> bounded.

Can't I always have finite number of small balls that will melt into the huge ball? - > totally bounded

So, why isn't every bounded space also completely bounded?

Answer (score 1):

Let $d$ be the discrete metric on $\Bbb N$:

$$d(m,n)=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }m=n\\
1,&\text{if }m\ne n\;.
\end{cases}$$

The space $\langle\Bbb N,d\rangle$ is clearly bounded: $\Bbb N\subseteq B(0,2)$, for instance, where $B(x,r)$ is the open ball of radius $r$ centred at $x$. However, there is no finite $F\subseteq\Bbb N$ such that

$$\bigcup_{n\in F}B(n,1)=\Bbb N\;,$$

since $B(n,1)=\{n\}$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$. In fact in this space

$$\bigcup_{n\in A}B(n,1)=A$$

for each $A\subseteq\Bbb N$.

This example shows that balls of small radius in a metric space don’t necessarily fit together the way you might expect on the basis of experience with the Euclidean spaces $\Bbb R^n$ with the usual Euclidean metric.

To make matters worse, we can start with any totally bounded metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$ and find a bounded metric $d'$ on $X$ that generates the same topology and is not totally bounded. Since $X$ is not totally bounded, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that no finite family of open balls of radius $\epsilon$ covers $X$. For $x,y\in X$ let

$$d'(x,y)=\min\{d(x,y),2\epsilon\}\;;$$

it’s straightforward to check that $d'$ is a metric on $X$ that generates the same topology as $d$. Clearly $\langle X,d'\rangle$ is bounded: $d'(x,y)\le 2\epsilon$ for all $x,y\in X$. But $B_d(x,\epsilon)=B_{d'}(x,\epsilon)$ for each $x\in X$, so $\langle X,d'\rangle$ and $\langle X,d\rangle$ have exactly the same open balls of radius $\epsilon$, and we already know that no finite family of them covers $X$. Thus, $\langle X,d'\rangle$ is not totally bounded.